# Background Image in head or body?

Tags: javascript, html, image, background

So. I went to W3Schools to try get some help, but I don't know why my Background Image won't show up...

```html
<body>
  <style>
    body {
      background-image: url(../Payday%202/download%20(2).jpg); --Image
      background-repeat: no-repeat; --No Repeat
      background-color: #000000 --When image ends, blackness!
    }
  </style>
--Code here--
</body>
```

I'm not sure if It needs to go into The head, because when I tried that, that didn't work either. Any help?

Comment: Typically style tags go into the `<head>`, and even better if you're referencing an [external file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link). Also in you background-image, you're missing `"`s around the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the style should typically be in the Head tags.

```
<head>
  <style>
    body {
      background-image: url("../Payday%202/download%20(2).jpg"); --Image
      background-repeat: no-repeat; --No Repeat
      background-color: #000000; --When image ends, blackness!
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
--Code here--
</body>
```

Even better if if you make an external style sheet which you reference in your HTML.

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
--Code here--
</body>
```

In style.css (in the same directory as your HTML file) you would put

```
body {
      background-image: url("../Payday%202/download%20(2).jpg"); --Image
      background-repeat: no-repeat; --No Repeat
      background-color: #000000; --When image ends, blackness!
}
```

You also want to make sure your image is in the location you are specifying, if the resource isn't there it wont show. Another tip would be name your files and directories without special characters (like spaces and parenthesis). Making your directory ../Payday02/download2.jpg is much safer than ../Payday%202/download%20(2).jpg.

Answer (score 0):

Well first I think the style block should go into the head tag, also make sure the image you are referencing actually exists at that url. You could also try wrapping the url in quotes as in url("path to imag"); also I hope those words with the -- prefix are not part of your real code

Answer (score 0):

Add Full File name and have no spaces

```html
<body>
  <style>
    body {
      background-image: url(http://localhost/site/images/fullfilepath.jpg); --Image
      background-repeat: no-repeat; --No Repeat
      background-color: #000000 --When image ends, blackness!
    }
  </style>
--Code here--
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

this should solve your problem, right the css style tag in the head of the page

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    body {
      background-image: url(../Payday%202/download%20(2).jpg); --Image
      background-repeat: no-repeat; --No Repeat
      background-color: #000000 --When image ends, blackness!
    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>
--Code here--
</body>
</html>
```